# AvalonDockの「Dock As Tabbed Document」を無効化したい

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

お世話になります。

下図 Visual Studioのような、
・赤枠(下部でタブ選択可能)
・青枠(上部でタブ選択可能)
のようなタブ機能を含めたアプリを作りたい為、
WPF+AvalonDockを用いています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかしながらタブ機能だけが欲しく、
LayoutAnchorableの「×ボタン」「Float機能」「Dock機能」「Dock As Tabbed Document機能」「AutoHide機能」「Hide機能」は不要と考えているため、
「CanAutoHide」や「CanClose」でFalseを行っているのですが、
「DockAsTabbedDocument」のみ無効化する方法がわかりません。

下記XAMLのコードを添付いたしますので、下記方法をご存知でしたら、
ご教示いただけないでしょうか。
・「DockAsTabbedDocument」の機能を無効化する方法
　※出来れば右クリック時も含め「hide」や「Dock」などのコンテキストメニューの表示すら無効化したい。
※参考までに「上図画像のタブ機能のみ表現するコントロール」ももしご存知であればご教示いただきたいです。

環境は下記です。
Visual Studio 2017 Community
C#(.net framework 4.5.2)
WPF
AvalonDock(3.4.17280.14430)
※https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959291/can-i-customize-avalondock-context-menu
　こちらのリンクも見たのですが、具体的にどのようにコードを修正すればよいのかわからず、
　苦戦しております。
　何卒ご教示の程よろしくお願いいたします。

```
 <Grid>

    <ad:DockingManager 
        x:Name="_dockingManager"
        Grid.Row="1"
        AllowMixedOrientation="True"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="1">
        <ad:DockingManager.Theme>
            <ad:MetroTheme />
        </ad:DockingManager.Theme>

        <ad:LayoutRoot>
            <ad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ad:LayoutAnchorablePane DockWidth="200" >
                    <ad:LayoutAnchorable CanAutoHide="False" CanTogglePin="False" CanFloat="False" CanClose="False" CanHide="False" Title="A">
                        <TextBox/>
                    </ad:LayoutAnchorable>
                    <ad:LayoutAnchorable CanAutoHide="False" CanTogglePin="False" CanFloat="False" CanClose="False" CanHide="False" Title="B">
                        <Button Content="Button3"/>
                    </ad:LayoutAnchorable>
                    <ad:LayoutAnchorable CanAutoHide="False" CanTogglePin="False" CanFloat="False" CanClose="False" CanHide="False" Title="C">
                        <Button Content="Button3"/>
                    </ad:LayoutAnchorable>
                </ad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
           </ad:LayoutPanel>
        </ad:LayoutRoot>
    </ad:DockingManager>
</Grid>
```

Comment: DockingManagerのDocumentContextMenuまたはAnchorableContextMenuに{x:Null}指定することで無事コンテキストメニューを非表示にすることが出来ました。早速のご回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

タブヘッダーのコンテキストメニューは`DockingManager`の`DocumentContextMenu`または`AnchorableContextMenu`プロパティで変更可能です。表示したくない場合は`{x:Null}`を指定してください。